# Excel - Cambiar dato del nombre de una tabla para que se adapte a la hoja correspondiente, segun mes y año

Tags: excel, date, caracteres, concatenación

Estoy armando unas planillas en Excel para Administrar un Edificio de apartamentos. En una parte he creado unas tablas que manejan lo referido a los ingresos y los egresos (cuenta corriente del Banco), y le he puesto el nombre a esas tablas así:

> CC_ENERO_2011, CC_FEBRERO_2011, ………., respectivamente para cada mes y referidas a ese año, en este caso particular 2011 o cualquier otro año.

La idea es crear un libro en Excel por cada año y que contenga hojas con los meses correspondientes.

Mi pregunta es si es posible referenciar o parametrizar los nombres de mes y año, en el nombre de una tabla, para cuando se crea una hoja por cada mes, esos datos de mes y año se cambien de acuerdo a alguna referencia en alguna celda.
Esto seria para no tener que cambiar todos los meses datos manualmente para adaptar la planilla y las formulas que utilizan dichas tablas.

Amplio la informacion:

Si bien con este formato la formula no da error, el resultado es 0. Al evaluar la formula no toma a la tabla correspondiente, en este caso
("CC_";$G$8;"_";$I$8) que se convierte en ("CC_CC_ENERO_2011"), supongo que queda como texto y no lo relaciona con el rango de la tabla para que encuentre el dato buscado.

Formula original, que funciona bien:

=SI.ERROR(INDICE(CC_ENERO_2011;COINCIDIR(' Datos A'!B70;CC_ENERO_2011[CONCEPTO CC];0);3);0)

Formula despues con CONCATENAR:

=SI.ERROR(INDICE(CONCATENAR("CC_";$G$8;"*";$I$8);COINCIDIR(' Datos A'!B70;CONCATENAR("CC*";$G$8;"_";$I$8;"[CONCEPTO CC]");0);3);0)

donde: 
***  $G$8 es el MES correspondiente  y $I$8 el AÑO correspondiente, ambos estan en 2 casillas bien identificadas que se cambia el contenido manualmente cuando se genera la hoja de ese mes y año.
***  ' Datos A'!B70 ----  B70 es el dato buscado en la hoja Datos A, en este caso se refiere a la Unidad (apartamento), por cada apartamento hay una celda.

Las tablas  CC (cuenta corriente) estan en una sola hoja, son 12 tablas (una por cada mes), bien identificadas.
Por cada mes genero una hoja para los detalles de gastos de Administracion donde en una columna utilizo la formula anterior para tomar el pago de los Copropietarios desde la hoja correspondiente a la CC.
Ademas tengo 2 hojas mas de Datos para listas desplegables, pero que no afectan a esa formula.

Me interesa automatizar el concepto de MES Y AÑO, ya que cuando genero las hojas con los meses (12) en cada año, tengo que cambiar el nombre correspondiente. Se puede hacer manualmente por supuesto, pero estoy viendo esa posibilidad para simplificar y mejorar otras planillas. Cuando existen muchos apartamentos es mas complicado.

Comment: Bienvenido @user108091 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No tengo muy claro qué es lo que pretendes obtener, pero sí puedo sugerirte que si todos tus ingresos y egresos van a tener los mismos campos, ponlos juntos en la misma hoja, y luego puedes resumir tus datos con tablas dinámicas por meses, trimestres, anuales, etc. Trabajar en 12 hojas es mucho más incómodo y menos efectivo que trabajar en una sola hoja, si todos los datos tienen la misma estructura.

Comment: Amplie la información en la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma de obtener el nombre de la hoja empleando la función `=CELDA("nombrearchivo")`

Lo anterior, devolverá la ruta del archivo, más el nombre de la hoja donde halla sido escrita dicha función, siendo `"nombrearchivo"` una variable de tipo texto reservada del propio Excel.

En este enlace se explica con más detalle cómo [Obtener el nombre de una hoja](http://javiermozo-excel-explicado.blogspot.com/2012/04/obtener-el-nombre-de-una-hoja.html) mediante las funciones `EXTRAER` o `DERECHA`, `LARGO` y `ENCONTRAR`.

> No obstante lo anterior, considero que al manejarse diferentes años y fechas, se podría incurrir en errores involuntarios para obtener el código `CC_MES_AÑO`.

Mi sugerencia es que se emplee fechas, por ejemplo: el primer día laborable del mes, digamos `02/09/2019` o cuando ocurre la operación bancaria de interés.

Para lograr lo anterior, se tendría que extraer el mes y el año, asimismo estos datos irían concadenados con la cta. corriente del banco respectiva:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La expresión:

```
=B2&"_"&MAYUSC(TEXTO(MES(A2);"mmmm"))&"_"&AÑO(A2)
```

Quiere decir lo siguiente:

```
=B2               /* Tomamos el valor de la celda B2: cta corriente */
    &"_"&         /* Unir el valor anterior con el que viene */
                  /* pero incluyéndose underline: _ */

          MAYUSC(      /* convertir el texto en mayuscula*/
               TEXTO(
                   MES(A2); /* Convertir la fecha de A2 en mes*/
                   "mmmm" /* el formato del mes sea su nombre completo*/
                    )
                )

    &"_"&        /* Unir el valor anterior con el que viene */
                 /* pero incluyéndose underline: _ */
AÑO(A2)          /* Convertir la fecha de A2 en año*/
```

> Nótese también que el operador `&` es equivalente al `;` o `,` *-dependiendo la configuración de vuestro Sistema Operativo **(SO)**-* que se emplea en la función `CONCATENAR`

```
=CONCATENAR(B2;"_";MAYUSC(TEXTO(MES(A2);"mmmm"));"_";AÑO(A2))
```

> Pero la función `CONCATENAR` también admite el operador: `&`

```
=CONCATENAR(B2&"_";MAYUSC(TEXTO(MES(A2);"mmmm"));"_"&AÑO(A2))
```

Comment: Amplie la información en la pregunta

Comment: Entiendo @user108091 que al tener datos sensibles como cuentas bancarias y demás, se omita capturas de pantalla en la ampliación de la pregunta... pero sin ello estamos algo ciegos para orientarte mejor. No obstante cómo se busca optimizar el flujo actual de trabajo, excel cuenta con una herramienta muy útil: **"tablas"** (no las dinámicas), *-este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPoy_2f9qfY) te pondrá en la dirección correcta-*, sugiero que se revise porque no tendrás que actualizar fórmulas después, sólo definir una plantilla base y duplicar el archivo para los siguientes años.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido podrias utilizar la funcion `=concatenar(Texto1;Texto2;)`

Por ejemplo:

```
=CONCATENAR("CC_";A1;"_";A2)
```

Donde en la celda A1 alimentarias el mes y en la celda A2 alimentas el año.

Comment: Amplie la información de la pregunta, hice la prueba con CONCATENAR pero no me toma la tabla, supongo que lo considera como texto y no lo relaciona con la tabla existente.